# Cannot pass dictionary as an argument to a VBA function

Tags: ms-access, dictionary, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a VBA function that is supposed to take a Dictionary as an argument:

```
Function ShowDict(Dict1 As Dictionary)
   For Each x In Dict1
        MsgBox (Dict1.Item(x))
   Next
End Function
```

And I am trying to call it the following way:

```
Dim Dict As Dictionary
Set Dict = Dictionary
Dict.Add "Owner", "John"
Dict.Add "Employee", "Sam"
ShowDict (Dict)
```

I did select Microsoft Scripting References from the References prior to defining the Dictionary. However, I get a compile error stating '**Argument not optional**' when I try to call the function using 'Dict' as the parameter. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `ShowDict` is implicitly taking the `Dict1` parameter `ByRef`, but the `ShowDict (Dict)` call is explicitly passing the `Dict` argument `ByVal`. Drop the parentheses if you're not using a function's return value... and write a `Sub` if you're writing a procedure that does not return a value. `Function` members should return something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make these 2 changes (`New Dictionary` and `ShowDict Dict`):

```vb
Dim Dict As Dictionary
'Set Dict = Dictionary
Set Dict = New Dictionary
Dict.Add "Owner", "John"
Dict.Add "Employee", "Sam"
'ShowDict (Dict)
ShowDict Dict
```

Also I suggest you add `Option Explicit` to the code module's Declarations section and include `Dim x` in your `ShowDict` function.  The absence of those does not contribute to the immediate problem, but adding them could prevent other problems in the future.